# Why does HTTP request work locally and on webspace and not on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: javascript, php, request, raspberry-pi, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem: I want to call a function via JS that sends a PHP request to my PHP file. It works locally, but not on the Raspberry Pi 3 and I don't know why. Do you have any tips? I would be very grateful.

HTML + GIF:

[image]

```html
<li class="cd-single-point" id="21" style="top:21%; right:5%;" onclick="pinStatusAendern(21, 1)">
  <a class="cd-img-replace" href="#0">Mehr Informationen</a>
  <div class="cd-more-info cd-left">
    <h2>Heutige Eingang der Siedlung</h2>
    <p>Heutiger Eingang von der Reifenwerksiedlung&nbsp;</p>                                 
    <a href="#0" class="cd-close-info cd-img-replace">Schließen</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS-Function:

```js
function pinStatusAendern(DBID, PinStatus) {

  var punkt = document.getElementById(DBID);

  if (!punkt.classList.contains("is-open")) {
    PinStatus = 0;
  } else {
    PinStatus = 1;
  }
  // Requestobjekt
  request = null;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e1) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      } catch (e2) {
        console.log("Anfrage nicht möglich.");
      }
    }
  }

  // Anfrage senden, wenn Requestobjekt vorhanden
  if (request != null) {
    // HTTP-POST
    request.open('POST', 'http://localhost/semikurs/pages/karte/php/verarbeitung.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send('DBID=' + DBID + '&PinStatus=' + PinStatus);
  }
}
```

PHP-File:

```php
<?php

require_once "../../../important/1-config.php";

GLOBAL $db;

if ($_POST["PinStatus"] == 0 || $_POST["PinStatus"] == 1) {

  $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE haeuser SET PinStatus = :pinstatus WHERE DBID = :DBID");
  $stmt->execute([
   "pinstatus" => $_POST["PinStatus"],
   "DBID" => $_POST["DBID"]
  ]);

}

?>
```

Comment: What are the error messages? More information is required to determine any problem.